# devices that can be turned on when something goes wrong on a server

Tags: monitoring

I have a computer that monitors some servers. I would like to connect a device to the computer that can be turned on (like a siren or police light) when some anomalies are detected on the server. Essentially - I'd run a script to turn on the device and then power it off.

Thanks!

mc

Comment: To those voting to migrate.  I don't believe this is a better fit for superuser.  Having an out-of-band notification system is something many system administrators may find useful.

Answer (score 1):

X10 Serial -> relay/power control

http://www.smarthome.com/1140/X10-Activehome-CM11A-Computer-Interface-CM11A/p.aspx

Alternatively, power strip that is IP accessible and controllable via SNMP or Telnet with an expect script.  APC makes one that is fairly workable that we use for a stonith handler.

D to A converter, allows you to control a relay attached to the serial port.

Sparkfun makes a USB relay.

Arduino boards can be handy

Answer (score 1):

There many devices designed for notifying deaf/hard-of-hearing people when an incoming phone has been made.  Many would allow you to setup indicator light anywhere you have an analog phone line.  All you need is a modem on your monitoring system to call the number.

- http://www.google.com/search?q=deaf+phone+ringer+light
- http://www.harriscomm.com/catalog/default.php?cPath=1215_1048

If you get a voice modem on your monitoring system you may be also able to have it call and leave you a message on a cell phone in case the network is down.

Answer (score 0):

Do not underestimate the value of scrolling LED sineage! A lot of those signs are USB connectable which allows you to program their messages on the fly. Handy for indicating which widget is on the blink.

Comment: Any recommendations for LED sineage?

Comment: @Mark I haven't bought any myself, but other departments at work have used them. I can't recommend anything in any meaningful way. The google term "scrolling LED signs" will bring buckets of hits.